# pdftex.def error - 'pdftex' requires pdfTex

Tags: pdftex

[image]

This is an error that appears everytime I try to build the output of my document though texnic centre. As you can see in the image, the error is: "option pdftec requires pdftex, but pdftex features are mssing". What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome! Probably you are compiling with `tex` or `latex` rather than `pdftex` or `pdflatex`. `tex` will execute `pdftex`, for example, but with a non-PDF output option so that pdfTeX features are disabled. Check if you can compile from the command line, if so, look at the settings of your editor to correct the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The screen shot shows that `xelatex` is used, but the graphics/color driver `pdftex.def` was requested. Likely some graphics or color package (e.g. `graphics`, `graphicx`, `color`, `xcolor`) was loaded with option `pdftex`.

This is wrong, because pdfTeX ≠ XeTeX.

Remove the driver option `pdftex`. Usually XeTeX or pdfTeX in PDF mode are detected automatically (or specify the *correct* driver option).